# Python fails to output ANSI color codes for the terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, ansi-colors

I have a very simple python +2.7 file which contains the following code which (when run in a terminal) outputs ANSI color codes for both string prints.

```
# coding=utf8

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'

print "\033[95mWorks fine\033[0m"
print '\033[95mWorks fine\033[0m'
print bcolors.OKBLUE, "Fails to work", bcolors.ENDC
```

How come the third print statement fails to produce any color in the terminal? Is there something I should know about using utf8 files?

System: ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You're not using utf8 here, it's all ASCII. But that should make it *more* likely to work.

Answer (score 3):

To sovle your problem your just need to `import os` and add `os.system("")` at the beginning of code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this works and what it does?

Answer (score 1):

**Single**-quotes and **double**-quotes are different in most other languages.  Not python.  Here are screenshots showing that the script should have worked (perhaps OP has applied some palette such as *solarized* which is confusing things—it is possible to reassign *any* of those colors on a terminal which imitates xterm):

[image: double-quotes]

[image: single-quotes]

Here's the so-called color cube from xterm (which you likely have seen):

[image: xterm color-cube]

and (some terminal emulators came late to the party), anything that implements the xterm control sequence can reprogram it, like this using reversed colors:

[image: reversed color-cube]

Comment: Um... you realize that the first two lines work fine right?

Comment: Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/fcWQs If this was a problem of single or double quotes one of the first two prints would fail.

Comment: Blue as requested.  There's something odd about your screenshot, since 94 is blue, 95 is magenta.

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. Other languages may distinguish between single and double quotes, but not Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class ConsolePrint(object):
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

    def print_warning(self, msg):
        print(self.WARNING + msg)

    def print_error(self, msg):
        print(self.FAIL + self.BOLD + msg)

    def print_info(self, msg):
        print(self.OKBLUE + msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cp = ConsolePrint()
    cp.print_warning("WARNING print text {0}".format(100))
    cp.print_error("ERROR print text {0}".format(200))
    cp.print_info("INFO print text {0}".format(300))
```

Comment: All this will do is remove the blanks between the escape sequences and the string. I doubt that will make much difference.

Comment: Oddly, this only prints color for the second error message: http://imgur.com/Iut240P